# AWS S3 authorization mechanism - Signature 4

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently struggling with getting a S3 download link working. I've been using [this code](http://dev.wattswork.com/make-signed-urls-for-amazon-s3-with-php/) as reference but when I try to open the file, I get the error:

> The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please
>   use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

I tried a few other scripts floating around, but all ended with some other error message.
**Is there an easy way to migrate the script I'm using to make it work with Signature v4?**

**UPDATE**: as suggested by hjpotter92, I used the AWS-SDK and came up with this working code:

```
$client = S3Client::factory([
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
  'signature'    => 'v4',
  'credentials' => [
    'key'    => '12345',
    'secret' => 'ABCDE'
  ]
]);

$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
  'Bucket' => '###name###',
  'Key'    => $fileName
]);

$request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+2 minutes');
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
return $presignedUrl;
```

Comment: AWS-PHP-SDK provides a method to generate signed URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#creating-a-pre-signed-url